# click on a button in selenium using list and class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I click on the button new account, that will in turn refresh the page and some more UI elements gets displayed?

id="primNav">

class="active">

a id="primNavAccountCreateNew" onclick="return false;" href="">**New 
account** a>

/li>

I tried using driver.findElement(By.id, By.name, By.linkText). But it's not working.

Comment: please copy and paste HTML code correctly to help you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us what error you are getting. The following code should work.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='primNavAccountCreateNew' and @href='']")).click;

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`driver.findElement(By.id("primNav")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New account ")).click();
```